# InvoiceId returns null on stripe c#

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I've problem when I tried to get invoice id it returns null 
that's my code :

```
       var myCharge = new StripeChargeCreateOptions();
        myCharge.Amount = (Int32)(amount*100);
        myCharge.Currency = "usd";
        myCharge.ReceiptEmail = stripeEmail;
        myCharge.Description = Description;
        myCharge.SourceTokenOrExistingSourceId = stripeToken;
        myCharge.Capture = true;
        myCharge.CustomerId = customer.Id;

        var chargeService = new StripeChargeService(token);
        StripeCharge stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(myCharge);
        string Invoice= stripeCharge.Invoice.Id;
```

Invoice always returns with null , any one know the reason ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [invoice property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-invoice) only exists on the charge object if the charge is the payment of a subscription invoice - i.e., if you are using Stripe's [Billing API](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart). In this case you're just creating a normal charge that is not linked to any invoice, so it's normal that the field is null.

Comment: Thanks Karl for reply, I checked that but i found Stripe's Billing API using interval in plan and i didn't find way to use it for one time and apply payment at same time of creating plan and subscription